# move_uploaded_file() no such file directory found

Tags: php

I am currently facing an issue with uploading files to my database using php. I had written the php upload code and the connection code, but i am facing problem with the move_uploaded_file function. According to my research i came to know that this is error is not new, but the thing is i changed the permission levels to full control. And also went to php.ini file and checked whether upload_file = on or not and also gone through the maximum file size. After seeing this error i found that i should create a new directory as it is not found.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/hello.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\upload\upload.php on line 22

Can you please tell me where should i create a new directory ?

```
 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="upload/";

 // new file size in KiloByte
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;


 // make file name in lower case
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);


 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
// i am getting error in the next line and i already created upload folder.
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES('$final_file')";
  mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: you need a full path

Comment: Can we have a code sample from your script ?

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code, i had updated the code now

Comment: Your script seems to be located in the upload/ directory, Am I right ? so I think this script tries to move the uploaded file in /upload/upload/ since the script is in the upload folder.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Thanks, i thought i will store in my scrpt folder directly, now i created a folder and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
 move_uploaded_file()
```

Follows an absolute path I think, so you should do something like this

```
$folder = dirname(__DIR__).'/upload';
```

Comment: not really. m_u_f will work with relative paths, but the directories in that path MUST exist - it won't create them for you.

Comment: Hmm then he should add this line
    if(!file_exist($folder)){ 
        mkdir($folder);
    }
This way you can see where the folder is being created